# How to drop all but last cell in CSV using CMD

Tags: csv, filter, cmd, tasklist

my goal is to write a script that will monitor process memory usage and run % based comparison on it to determine if there is a memory leak in the said process.

I am using the following command to get the momory usage of the process:

tasklist /fi "imagename eq %PROCESS%" /FO csv | findstr K

SAMPLE:
"cmd.exe","11640","Console","1","3,160 K"

This gives me a CSV file with last cell being the memory usage. I have two problems that I need help with.

Problem 1) How do I drop all but the last cell so that I can then assign the Kb used to a variable for comparison.

Problem 2) How do I get rid of the comma in the number? That kind of makes using comma as delim hard :/

Is there a better command than tasklist for this? I just need the raw number that the program is using, it can be in KB or MB.

Id love to be able to not have dependencies, but if I have to have dependencies I can include them with the batch.

Also is there any way for findstr to not return the entire line?

Thanks for any help! Ive been trying to get this solved for two days now with not much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (memcsv.csv) DO CALL :process %%i 

GOTO :EOF
:process
SET memsize=%~5
SET memsize=%memsize:,=%
ECHO memsize found = %memsize%
GOTO :eof
```

This should get your output into a variable called `memsize`.

It uses a file `memcsv.csv` as input, but you could replace `mmcsv.csv` with

```
'tasklist /fi "imagename eq %PROCESS%" /FO csv ^| findstr Mem'
```

to operate directly on the output of `FINDSTR`. Your resultant line would thus be

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq %PROCESS%" /FO csv ^| findstr Mem') DO CALL :process %%i
```

which, for ease of legibility could be entered as

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (
  'tasklist /fi "imagename eq %PROCESS%" /FO csv ^| findstr Mem'
  ) DO CALL :process %%i
```

Note that the line-breaks are specific - before and after the single-quote.

Also that the single-quotes are REQUIRED and that there is a caret (`^`) before the pipe (`|`) which tells `cmd` that the pipe is part of the command to be executed, not part of the `FOR` command

---

Edit to add explanation of HOW.

The ouput of the `tasklist...|findstr...` can be used as input to a `for/f` as if it was a file. All you need do is to surround the command with `SINGLE-QUOTES` and ensure that redirectors like `| < >` are "escaped" by a caret.

FOR /F "reads" the "file" line-by-line, assigning (by default) the first "token" in the line to the "metavariable" (the loop-control variable, `%%i` in the above case). This behaviour canbe modified by the addition of control-clauses to the `FOR/F`. You may use `tokens=x,y,z" for instance to assign token number x, number y and number z to %%i, %%j, %%k respectively.

TOKENS are counted from 1 and have a value of the line contents up to a (series of) delimiter(s). By default, delimiters are spaces, commas, semicolons and TABs, so a line

```
TOKEN_ONE TOKEN_2,TOKEN_THREE;Token_FOUR
```

when seen by

```
for /f "tokens=1,3,4" %%i in (filecontainingaboveline) do
```

would set `%%i`=TOKEN_ONE `%%j`=TOKEN_THREE `%%k`=Token_FOUR

Using "delims=" turns OFF the delimiters and hence the ENTIRE line is assigned to the metavariable.

HENCE, in the above code, the entire line is assigned to `%%i` and delivered to the subroutine `:process`.

From `:process`'s point-of-view, it has been given the argument ** "cmd.exe","11640","Console","1","3,160 K"** which *it* interprets as a sequence of 5 parameters separated by commas - and a comma (or any other separator) WITHIN "quotes" is data, not a separator.

Parameter number 5 is accessed by `%5` - and that is `"3,160 K"` - including the quotes and comma.

The variable is set to the value of the fifth parameter - the tilde (`~`) means "remove enclosing quotes." Hence `memsize` acquires a value of `3,160 K`
The next `SET` replaces the string after the colon in the nominated variable with the string after the `=` - replace commas with nothing, and assign the result to the `memsize` variable.

The `goto :eof` means 'go to the physical end-of-file.` It is very specific - the colon MUST be present. Reaching end-of-file terminates a subroutine or batch-process.

To remove the last 2 characters of the variable, you could use

```
SET var=%var:0,~-2%
```

where `var` is the variable-name.

SEE

```
SET /?
```

from the prompt for documentation.

Also `GOTO /?` and `FOR/?` for more details on these commands...

Comment: What is the :EOF ? seems like the script will go nowhere when that line is reached?

Comment: I changed around the EOF stuff to the following code and now it seems to work well :) How would I also get rid of the "K" at the end of the memsize integer? And any spaces around, so that its just a raw number?


`SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /FO csv ^| findstr K') DO CALL :process %%i 

GOTO processend
:process
SET memsize=%~5
SET memsize=%memsize:,=%
ECHO memsize found = %memsize%
:processend`


Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Peter, I am trying to use SET var=%var:~-2% but that just displays the last two characters which are " K" a space and the K. I cant find anything about truncating things under SET /?

Comment: Um - should be `:~0,-2` - now fixed. Sure there is documentation - on the second page. I uses the `PATH` variable, but it will work on any variable. The `:~0,-2` combo means from the first character (ie character 0) to the (last -2)

Comment: Hmm running into an issue, looks like CMD runs out of allocated memory (which I guess is 4 megabytes) and crashes? Takes about a minute or two of running. I need this thing to run for at least 4 days. Im guessing its because this command takes up so much. I dont need it to go through all instances of a process, any way to simplify it? Perhaps not include it in a FOR loop?

Comment: Looks like there is some sort of memory leak in that for loop, got around it by having that be in a temporary bat file that gets called to get the variable. if you have any other ides please let me know :)

Comment: Cannot see that these few instructions would lead to the problem you describe. You'd need to put the issue in context. This code will execute just once - what is it that causes it to be run for at least 4 days? And `TASKLIST` isn't slow - need to see a lot more of what you are doing to analyse the issue - and better as a new question (they're not that severely rationed, are they?) since this running-out-of-memory issue has little to do with this question's subject.